# решения по запуску java приложений у пользователя без jvm

Tags: java, javac

вот я написал от же helloworld.java ,какие минимальные требования для запуска на сторонней машине (что нужно установить чтоб заработало), и какие есть решения по установке этой всячины и собственно запуску программы ибо некоторые пишут bat-ники для jar, а некоторые используют самораспаковывающийся архив на который агрятся антивирусы?

Comment: 1. Ожидать что пользователь поставит jvm.  2. Притащить ее с собой.

Comment: а есть способ с bat-ником чтобы он сам установил jvm и поставил Path?

Comment: а зачем это Вам?

Comment: имеется юзер к которому я явиться не могу, но могу заставить его ткнуть два раза лкм, хочу написать батник чтоб установился jvm

Answer (score 0):

java код собирается в специальный байт-код. Байт-код отдается в jvm, которая транслирует его в команды для процессора и системные вызовы. Процессоры бывают разные, операционные системы тоже, и под каждую из них нужна своя виртуальная машина. Нет виртуальной машины - нет даже теоретической возможности исполнить байткод, потому что процессор понятия не имеет что это

Можете собрать свой инсталятор, который поставит вашу программу и виртуальную машину. Есть всякие упростители процессов, например Smart Install Maker